# How to get Cache Value of a Field

Tags: acumatica

How to get the inputted value field in Acumatica?
I'm working on the `View.Cache.Cached`, I seem lost.

Do I need it to set to a DAC?

Comment: Have you set the "CommitChanges" to `true` for that field? If you have, then the value will be in the corresponding record of the DAC in the `Cache.Updated` collection of the Updated Records

Comment: It is as Samvel Petrosov said, except for the vexing exception that is 'Selected' field used in processing screens which can only be reliably read in the context of the processing delegate handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the "CommitChanges" to true for that field? If you have, then the value will be in the corresponding record of the DAC in the Cache.Updated collection of the Updated Records – Samvel Petrosov.

Yea, I forgot to set the Commit Changes for the field. Thanks, it works now! :D